# Can I check the actual type of void*?

Tags: c++, casting, legacy-code

I have to use a legacy C library in my C++ code. One of the functions of that library looks like this:

```
int legacyFunction(int (*userDefinedPredicateFunction)(void*), void* structure, otherArgs...);
```

This `legacyFunction()` calls `userDefinedPredicateFunction()` inside itself passing `structure` as argument to it. I have multiple custom predicate functions to be used with the above function. Each of these functions works different from the others and expects an argument to be of a strictly defined type to work properly:

```
int userDefinedPredicateFunction1(void* structure)
{
    const expectedType1* const s = reinterpret_cast<expectedType1*>(structure);
    // Check s conditions...
}

int userDefinedPredicateFunction2(void* structure)
{
    const expectedType2* const s = reinterpret_cast<expectedType2*>(structure);
    // Check s conditions...
}

int userDefinedPredicateFunction3(void* structure)
{
    const expectedType3* const s = reinterpret_cast<expectedType3*>(structure);
    // Check s conditions...
}
```

The problem is that these predicate functions are not safe to use - passing an argument of not the expected type to them will lead to an undefined mess. I need to somehow check the type of the argument and throw if it is not the expected type. `structure` is not polymorphic, so I cannot use `dynamic_cast` here.

The first thing comes to mind is to use a wrapper function like this one:

```
int legacyFunctionWrapper1(const Type1& structure, otherArgs...)
{
    return legacyFunction(
        userDefinedPredicateFunction1, &structure, otherArgs...);
}
```

This will let `structure` only to be of a one certain type expected by the predicate function, but a dedicated wrapper function is needed to be written to be used with each predicate function, which is undesirable.

Is there more elegant way to check the actual type of `void*` pointer?

Comment: `userDefinedPredicateFunction1(&structure)` in the last snippet calls the function, but I think you want to pass the function pointer

Comment: No a void* destroys all type information. That doesn't prevent you to write a typesafe wrapper though. Do a reinterpret_cast<void*> at the last possible moment.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't *call* `userDefinedPredicateFunction1` when you call `legacyFunction`. Secondly, how is the "predicate" function called? From where? How is the argument passed? Where and how do you set the argument? Please try to create something with is more like a [mre] than what you have now.

Comment: Do you have control over their allocation? Or can you enumerate the objects at a different place where you know their type?

Comment: In some form or fashion you have to define the real type of each function's parameter. This mapping is not going to appear out of thin air, by itself. You have to define it, somehow. Either via an explicit wrapper function, like that, or via template that gets instantiated for each wrapper function. Depending on the actual set of functions and their properties it might be possible to define a template and just instantiate it, in a compact manner, for each function, but that's probably as much as can be done here. Which approach is more "elegant" is purely a matter of opinion.

Comment: From your proposed wrapper it looks like you control when legacyFunction is called and what object is passed to it. So is this question just about you providing type safety during programming so that you don't accidentally call legacyFunction with incompatible type and function pairs? Or would legacyFunction call the passed function for different objects of different type on its own (like iterating through a data structure, for example)?

Comment: Sorry, my post was misleading and contained errors. Edited.

Comment: @Homer512 > `So is this question just about you providing type safety during programming so that you don't accidentally call legacyFunction with incompatible type and function pairs?` Yes, this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Does the original code have more than one argument in `userDefinedPredicateFunction` because with just the caller defined `structure` you might as well just pass the result of the predicate unless there is some more complex semantic going on.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, yes, the original code has more than one argument in `userDefinedPredicateFunction()`. `legacyFunction()` provides some additional arguments to`userDefinedPredicateFunction()` and shares some of the `otherArgs` with it (I omitted these details in the example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right path with that wrapper function. You can save yourself some work by making it a template. This should work:

```
using legacy_predicate = int (*)(void*);

template<class T>
void call_legacy(int (*predicate)(T*), T* obj, int otherargs)
{
    using pair_type = std::pair<int(*)(T*), T*>;
    pair_type realargs = std::make_pair(predicate, obj);
    legacy_predicate wrapper = +[](void* unsafe) -> int {
        pair_type& realargs = *static_cast<pair_type*>(unsafe);
        return realargs.first(realargs.second);
    };
    legacyFunction(wrapper, &realargs, otherargs);
}
```

Two things of note:

1. I avoided reinterpret-casting the function pointer since that is technically undefined behavior (though it should work in practice). This introduces some indirection and may be a bit slower
2. The trick is to turn a stateless lambda into a function pointer with the unary `+` operator

To make up for the indirection and maybe modernize the whole thing a bit, consider this:

```
template<class Functor>
void call_legacy(Functor predicate, int otherargs)
{
    legacy_predicate wrapper = +[](void* unsafe) -> int {
        Functor* predicate = static_cast<Functor*>(unsafe);
        return (*predicate)();
    };
    legacyFunction(wrapper, &predicate, otherargs);
}
```

This allows you to pass arbitrary functors, not just function pointers. So you can use it with lambdas or whatever you want. To get the old pattern, you wrap the object at the call site, maybe make it into a overload. Like this:

```
template<class T>
void call_legacy(int (*predicate)(T*), T* obj, int otherargs)
{
    // dispatch to overloaded interface described above
    return call_legacy([predicate, obj]() -> int {
          return predicate(obj);
    }, otherargs);
}
```

### Warning

This only works if legacyFunction does not store the passed void* beyond the runtime of the function. Beware of dangling pointers.

### Alternative

As I've mentioned, casting function pointers is undefined behavior, but it tends to work in simple cases. Rule of thumb: If your platform supports GTK+, it supports simple function pointer casts (because Gtk even does horrible things like changing the number of function arguments).

So this is the zero-overhead version:

```
using legacy_predicate = int (*)(void*);
template<class T>
void call_legacy(int (*predicate)(T*), T* obj, int otherargs)
{
    legacy_predicate unsafe = reinterpret_cast<legacy_predicate>(predicate);
    legacyFunction(unsafe, obj, otherargs);
}
```

Comment: The caveat here is that if `legacyFunction` stores the pointers and calls through them later `structure` will dangle

Comment: @Caleth Oh right, I forgot to add this note!

Comment: Yeah, my platform supports GTK+. Actually, the legacy library I am talking about is `XLib` :) I know, it is insanity to use it nowadays(even XLib documentation says it), but I need only very basic UI functionality and don't want to drag huge toolkits such as GTK/QT as a dependency for a several megabyte program. That's why I use it.

Comment: Only the first version is correct. While you can cast the function pointer to `void (*)(void *)` you may not call it with that signature, you have to cast it back to the original type. That also applies to the `void *` argument. In your second example you fail to cast the argument. In your third example you call the lambda taking no arguments with an extra `void*`. That might be standard conform in C due to the whole implicit-prototype mess but iirc not C++. In you fourth example you restore neither the type of the function nor the object.

Comment: The reason that all of them work is that pointer conversion is implementation defined and almost all implementation have it as NOP.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Please read again. The second example does cast the argument. The third example also compiles, as you can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/jGM3PvhWT I think you missed where I substituted the function pointer for a new pointer to the lambda.

Comment: @Homer512 My bad, I mistook the `otherargs` for the `void*`.